# How to get rows with values of a column matching the same sequence of another sequence

Tags: python, pandas

For example there's a DataFrame `df`. And I want sort the rows based on the sequence `s` in order to get `df_target`. What's the correct way to achieve this purpose?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3,4,2,5], 'b':['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 
'grape']})

s = [4,5,2,3]
df_target = pd.DataFrame({'a': [4,5,2,3], 'b':['orange', 'grape', 
'pear', 'apple']})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could temporarily set the index to `a` and then index using the list:

```
In[209]:
df.set_index('a').loc[s].reset_index()
Out[209]: 
   a       b
0  4  orange
1  5   grape
2  2    pear
3  3   apple
```